# DND print script in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

I made a HTML script to quickly make a Dnd5 sheet.

This was a project done in two weeks, I don't know what to say else except I'm learning JS, CSS and HTML. I would love to learn how to make this better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">


<body>
<h1>
DND5 Quick Sheet
</h1>
<l><font size = "2">
this is for a quick C&P sheet, enter the details
in the former prompts and you'll have it on the page,
reload the page to change items. Please message me on 
<a href="https://discordapp.com/">Discord</a>
if you see or have ANY problems. (---)
</font></l> 
<small>
<script language = "JavaScript">
try{ 
var b = []; // the dialogue
var c = []; // prompts and inputs
var d = "<br>/#:";
var e = confirm("Click ok if you wish to make a sheet, clicking 
elsewhere will cancel this.")
if(e == true) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 23; ++x) { //plus one
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                b[x] = "Username: ";
                c[x] = "What username?";
                break;
            case 1:
                b[x] = "Name: "+d;
                c[x] = "Name of your character?";
                break;
            case 2:
                b[x] = "Race: ";
                c[x] = "Their race?";
                break;
            case 3:
                b[x] = "Level: ";
                c[x] = "Level? 1 to 20.";
                break;
            case 4: 
                b[x] = "Exp: ";
                c[x] = "Experience total?";
                break; 
            case 5:
                b[x] = "Class: ";
                c[x] = "Their class?";
                break;
            case 6:
                b[x] = "Subclasses: ";
                c[x] = "If any, Subclass / Subclasses?";
                break;
            case 7: 
                b[x] = "Alignment: "; 
                c[x] = "Their alignment?";
                break; 
            case 8: 
                b[x] = "Background: "+d; 
                c[x] = "background?";
                break;
            case 9:
                b[x] = "Hit dice: ";
                c[x] = "Their hit dice?";
                break;
            case 10:
                b[x] = "Armor: "; 
                c[x] = "If any, what armor?";
                break;
            case 11: 
                b[x] = "SPEED: "; 
                c[x] = "Their speed?";
                break;  
            case 12: 
                b[x] = "HP: "; 
                c[x] = "Their HP?";
                break;
            case 13: 
                b[x] = "AC: "+d; 
                c[x] = "Their AC total.";
                break;
            case 14: 
                b[x] = "Strength: "; 
                c[x] = "Strength,  4d6dl.";
                break; 
            case 15: 
                b[x] = "Dexterity: "; 
                c[x] = "Dexterity?";
                break; 
            case 16: 
                b[x] = "Constitution: "; 
                c[x] = "Constitution?";
                break; 
            case 17: 
                b[x] = "Intelligence: "; 
                c[x] = "Intelligence?";
                break;
            case 18: 
                b[x] = "Wisdom: ";
                c[x] = "Wisdom?";
                break;
            case 19:
                b[x] = "Charisma: "+d;
                c[x] = "Charisma?";
                break;
            case 20:
                b[x] = "Inventory: ";
                c[x] = "Items held?";
                break;
            case 21: 
                b[x] = "Weapons: ";
                c[x] = "Wepons held?";
                break; 
            case 22: 
                b[x] = "proficiency: ";
                c[x] = "Your Proficiencys? List bonus prof. tool prof. skill 
prof. weapons prof. armor prof.";
                break; 
        }
    c[x] = prompt(c[x]); 
    if(c[x] == null) continue;
    if(c[x].length > 1256) throw "Long String Error. [CE1]<br>";
    document.write("/#:", b[x]+c[x], "<br>");
        } 
    }
}
   catch (err) {
   document.write("Attempt again. <em>[[UNKOWN ERROR] CE0] 
    </em><br>"+err);
    }
    </script>

</small> <ul style="list-style-type:square;">

<l><b><font size = "2">Cedits</font><br></b></l>
<l><font size = "1">>--- Programmed This HTML Page<br></l>
<l>--- Inspired This</font><br></l>
<l><b><font size = "2">Resources</font></b><br></l>
<l><a href "https://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow.com</a> 
<br></l>
<l><a href "https://www.dndbeyond.com/">dndbeyond.com</a> 
<br></l>
</ul>

<p><font size = "1">
Apps Used --- anWriter free - Js Run - duckduckgo --- on android<br> 
[305[111]]<br> 
THANK YOU FOR YOUR USAGE OF THIS <br> 
<br>
DMY 8-2-2020 -- TILL NOW AND FOREVER 
</font> 
<p>
</body>
</html>
```